# Customize.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

first I want to apologize for my bad English! I've been developing Wordpress theme for some time, but I have a strange problem with WP_Customize_Control. When I install the theme on a fresh Wordpress installation, the colors of theme are not quite right and custom footer text also .. like the file /customizer.php/ is missing but he isn`t.. When I inspect the code I see the following code:

```
   <style type="text/css">
   #sbi_mod_error{ display: block; }
   </style>

   <style type="text/css">

    .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:visited {
        background-color: ;
    }

    .date-new,
    .btn-primary,
    .btn-primary-a,
    .btn-primary-a:link,
    .btn-primary-a:visited,
    div.hd-search #searchsubmit {
        background-color: ;
    }
    footer {
        background: ;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover,
    div.hd-search #searchsubmit:hover {
        background-color: ;
    }
    .navbar,
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: ;
    }   
    .widget-title,
    .cat>a {
        border-bottom: ;
    }
    .read-more {
        border: 1px solid ;
    }
    .widget ul li::before {
        color: ;
    }
    body {
        background: ;
    }

  </style>
  <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline 
  !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
  * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
  @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
  html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
  }
  </style>
```

when I go to "Customize", make changes and save it, everything is done. would some help me? It is my customize.php file:

```
    <?php

 // Customize Appearance Options
 function Clean_Blog_Customize_Register( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_link_color', array(
    'default' => '#000',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_btn_color', array(
    'default' => '#007bff',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_nav_color', array(
    'default' => '#262626',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_btn_hover_color', array(
    'default' => '#49a1ff',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_footer_color', array(
    'default' => '#1a1a1a',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_borders_color', array(
    'default' => '#007bff',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('lwp_background_color', array(
    'default' => '#f2f2f2',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_section('lwp_standard_colors', array(
    'title' => __('Standard Colors', 'CleanBlog'),
    'priority' => 30,
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_link_color_control', array(
    'label' => __('Link Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_link_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_btn_color_control', array(
    'label' => __('Button Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_btn_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_btn_hover_color_control', array(
    'label' => __('Button Hover Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_btn_hover_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_nav_color', array(
    'label' => __('Navigation Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_nav_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_footer_color', array(
    'label' => __('Footer Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_footer_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 
'lwp_borders_color', array(
    'label' => __('Bordes Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_borders_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize,
'lwp_background_color', array(
    'label' => __('Background Color', 'CleanBlog'),
    'section' => 'lwp_standard_colors',
    'settings' => 'lwp_background_color',
) ) );

// Add a footer/copyright information section.
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'text_blocks', array(
    'priority' => 500,
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'title' => __('Text Blocks', 'CleanBlog'),
    'description' => __( 'Set editable text for certain content.', 'CleanBlog'
 ),
     ) );   
$wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_footer_text' , array(
    'title' => __('Change Footer Text','CleanBlog'),
    'panel' => 'text_blocks',
    'priority' => 10
     ) );
 // Add setting
 $wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_text_block', array(
    'default' => __( 'default text', 'CleanBlog' ),
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
    ) );
 // Add control
 $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
 'custom_footer_text', array(
    'label' => __( 'Footer Text', 'CleanBlog' ),
    'section' => 'custom_footer_text',
    'settings' => 'footer_text_block',
    'type' => 'text'
)));
// End Adding a footer/copyright information section.

$wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_id', array(
    'priority' => 2,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'title' => __( 'Social Media Links', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => __( 'Description of what this panel does.', 'textdomain'
),
) );

//Facebook
$wp_customize->add_section( 'section_id', array(
    'priority' => 10,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'title' => __( 'Social Links', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
    'panel' => 'panel_id',
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'facebook_link', array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'facebook_link', array(
    'type' => 'url',
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'label' => __( 'Facebook URL', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
) );
//Twitter
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'twitter_link', array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'twitter_link', array(
    'type' => 'url',
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'label' => __( 'Twitter URL', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
) );
//YouTube
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'youtube_link', array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'youtube_link', array(
    'type' => 'url',
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'label' => __( 'YouTube URL', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
) );
//Linkedin
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'linkedin_link', array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'linkedin_link', array(
    'type' => 'url',
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'label' => __( 'Linkedin URL', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
) );
//google_plus
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'google_plus_link', array(
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'google_plus_link', array(
    'type' => 'url',
    'priority' => 10,
    'section' => 'section_id',
    'label' => __( 'Google Plus URL', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => '',
) ); 
 }
  // Sanitize text
  function sanitize_text( $text ) {
    return sanitize_text_field( $text );
 }

add_action('customize_register', 'Clean_Blog_Customize_Register');


  // Output Customize CSS
  function Clean_Blog_Customize_Css() 
  {     
  ?>

<style type="text/css">

    .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:visited {
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_link_color'); ?>;
    }

    .date-new,
    .btn-primary,
    .btn-primary-a,
    .btn-primary-a:link,
    .btn-primary-a:visited,
    div.hd-search #searchsubmit {
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_btn_color'); ?>;
    }
    footer {
        background: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_footer_color'); ?>;
    }
    .btn-primary:hover,
    div.hd-search #searchsubmit:hover {
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_btn_hover_color'); ?>;
    }
    .navbar,
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_nav_color'); ?>;
    }   
    .widget-title,
    .cat>a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid <?php echo
   get_theme_mod('lwp_borders_color'); ?>;
    }
    .read-more {
        border: 1px solid <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_borders_color'); ?>;
    }
    .widget ul li::before {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_borders_color'); ?>;
    }
    body {
        background: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_background_color'); ?>;
    }

 </style>
 <?php 
 }
 add_action('wp_head', 'Clean_Blog_Customize_Css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theme option default background-color set used code

```
background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('lwp_link_color','#b71757'); ?>;
```